# Ruby on Rails User Test Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Doing the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I'm getting strange error message when running the test.
My user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "wordpass", password_confirmation: "wordpass")
  end
  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name="      "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email= "      "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name= "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email= "a" * 256
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid? , "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end
  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end
  test "password should be a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

end
```

The user.rb :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :name, :email , :password, :password_confirmation
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }  
    validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

One of the errors seems to be from the user definition, but I cannot find the source of error. Is it something due related to "validates" in user.rb file ? Any help will be much appreciated !!

```
FAIL["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", UserTest, 0.061796445]
 test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (0.06s)
        "user@example.com" should be valid
        test/models/user_test.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserTest>'
        test/models/user_test.rb:32:in `each'
        test/models/user_test.rb:32:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_be_valid", UserTest, 0.080466737]
 test_should_be_valid#UserTest (0.08s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/user_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Don't use attr_accessor for anything that should be persisted in the database (name,email)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, one of the errors is due to @user being invalid in the first test. Do the following in rails console, this should print out errors on user model:

```
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "wordpass", password_confirmation: "wordpass")
@user.valid?
pp @user.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try different regex in user.rb

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Comment: regexes are often even more useful if they are explained a bit.

Comment: Try tis one: [link] (https://regex101.com/) . Paste the regex follows an explanation @Trilarion

Comment: Thanks. Still I think a compressed version of what regex101.com says would make the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

well everything looks fine. just run the command

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

and if this doesnt work either then

```
$rake db:delete
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

first one worked for me